# Using grep to print all of the matching strings not separated by a space

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm looking through a text file of emails and trying to get a list of ones from a certain domain.

I'm running:

```
grep -oh "\w*domain.com\w*" file.txt
```

This finds the lines, but only prints that "word", meaning that if I ran the command on this list:

```
foo abc@notit.com bar
baz bcd@domain.com abc
xyz cde@adomain.com defg
klmn def@notit.com ijk
yes efg@efg.domain.com no
```

It will return

```
domain.com
adomain.com
domain.com
```

I want it to return the entire email address with "domain.com" in it:

```
bcd@domain.com
cde@adomain.com
efg@efg.domain.com
```

Is this possible with `grep`? I need to tell it to not treat periods or `@` signs as word-breaks.

EDIT:  There is a bunch of irrelevant data on the same line that I would prefer not to have show up.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for

```
grep -ho '\S*domain.com\S*' file
```

where `\S` matches non-whitespace characters, so in this case `grep` will match everything between whitespaces with string "domain.com" in it.

Alternatively if you want to explicitly allow only `@` and `.` in the string (apart of alphanumeric characters obviously):

```
grep -ho '[[:alnum:].@]*domain.com[[:alnum:].]' file
```

This way `grep` will extract `user@domain.com` from the string `[user@domain.com]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but as I mentioned in the edit above, there is a lot of irrelevant data on the same line as the email.  Your second example doesn't seem to be working for me.  Any other ideas or information I could provide to help?

Edit:  I'm seeing now that there actually are no spaces in the list, but each email is between ' characters.

Comment: @Parker The second and third examples from my answer do take into account additional data in the same line.

Comment: The third command works perfectly for me with a slight modification:

    grep -ho '[[:alnum:].@]*domain.com' file

Comment: @Parker Well `grep -ho '[[:alnum:].@]*domain.com` works only if nothing is after "domain.com" or you want to drop it, for example "user@domain.com.us" the ".us" will be thrown away.

Comment: After playing with it some more I've had to add - and _ after the alnum portion since some addresses contained these but I didn't leave it on the end like you mentioned here because there is nothing after the .com in any of the domains.  If there was that would work.  Glad I learned something new today about grep :)

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
<file tr -cs '[[:alnum:].@-_]' '[\n*]' | grep domain\.com
bcd@domain.com
cde@adomain.com
efg@efg.domain.com
```